# Nuxt - get images from another folder

Tags: nuxt.js

I've got a Nuxt app as a part of another bigger project which has its own `content/images` folder.

**The problem:** when I'm in dev mode it fails to find at `localhost:3000/content/images/someimage.jpg` unless it's copied to `static/content/images` folder of Nuxt.

Is there a slightly more elegant way to fix it rather than copying the entire `content/images` folder to the Nuxt dir?